# Android: How to start and stop a loop that fires on a timer?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, handler, runnable

I have two buttons in my GUI. "ONE TURN" and "AUTO PLAY". I want the AUTO PLAY button to start automatically pressing the ONE TURN button on a timer, whose speed I will eventually control with a slider or something. However, I want it so that when I press the AUTO PLAY button again it stops automatically activating the first button. The auto play works, but stopping the auto play does not work, and I don't know how to stop it. Maybe I'm using the wrong solution entirely, or maybe I just don't know how to properly stop the runnable? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I have done a lot of searching and haven't found anything too useful. My AUTO PLAY on click code is below:

```
public void autoClick(final View view) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    isAutoPlaying = !isAutoPlaying;

    final View dummyView = view;
    Runnable runnable = null;

    if(isFirstAutoPlayClick) {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onClick(dummyView);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

            }
        };
        isFirstAutoPlayClick = !isFirstAutoPlayClick;
    }

    if(isAutoPlaying) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"isAutoPlaying is true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.post(runnable);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"isAutoPlaying is false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.removeCallbacks(null);
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the 
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55tHg.png)

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `handler.removeCallbacks(null)` to `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` see if it's working for you

**EDIT**
You need to move your handler local variable to class field too.

```
public class Activity{
    Handler handler = new Handler(); //<-- Put it here
    public void autoClick(final View view) {
         final Handler handler = new Handler(); //<-- Remove this
         ...
    }
}
```

So that when calling `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages()` you are referring to that initial handler instead of a new instance

Comment: Just noticed it may also caused by the referencing, try the edited solution

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote this up, but you solved it! Now I am kicking myself for not realizing that I was creating a new handler every click. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to help you. Maybe you can mark this as correct answer for me? Thanks anyway